# AC/DC Motor Running in the wrong direction

Tags: motor

So I have a floor buffer that has 115v AC motor on it. Recently the motor seems to be running in the wrong direction so that the driver flies off of it. I have replaced both rectifier bridges and the motor is still running in the wrong direction. There is no stationary switch or start/Run capacitors on this motor. It has the magentic field, Comuntator and 4 carbon brushes. This motor is also a variable speed with a speed controler.

Comment: I don't think you are telling the whole story here. The motor is called a universal motor, and the wiring of the rotor is typically in series with the stator. If you change the connections on either the rotor or stator the direction of rotation will change. Did you rewire the motor ..perhaps to replace a switch or AC cable?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine how a motor or controller could fail in any way that would make the motor run in the wrong direction. A wiring error or a failure of a system that includes the ability to select either direction of operation would seem the most likely problems. There is also the possibility that there is something about this that you gave not described properly.

Comment: Somebody swapped the connections to either the field winding or the rotor winding.